# Launch Photoswipe gallery by simple link

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

I use the photoswipe plugin:

```
(function(window, PhotoSwipe){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var options = {
            preventHide: true,
            getImageSource: function(obj) {
                return obj.url;
            },
            getImageCaption: function(obj) {
                return obj.caption;
            }
        },
        instance = PhotoSwipe.attach([
            { url: 'http://www.site.com/img/8896/ico5.jpg', caption: 'Image 001' },
            { url: 'http://www.site.com/img/8897/ico5.jpg', caption: 'Image 002' },
            { url: 'http://www.site.com/img/8898/ico5.jpg', caption: 'Image 003' },
            { url: 'http://www.site.com/img/8899/ico5.jpg', caption: 'Image 004' },
            { url: 'http://www.site.com/img/9000/ico5.jpg', caption: 'Image 005' },
            { url: 'http://www.site.com/img/9001/ico5.jpg', caption: 'Image 006' }
        ], options);

        instance.show(0);
    }, false);
}(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
```

I would like launch the gallery from a simple url in my page like this:

```
<a href="#" id="photo">
    <img src="/img/ico_photo1.png" border="0" /><br>
    Gallery
</a>
```

But I don't know how do it; can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this code work for me:

```
function startSwipe()
{

(function(window, PhotoSwipe){

var
options = {
preventHide: false,
loop: false,
allowUserZoom = false,
getImageSource: function(obj){
return obj.url;
},
getImageCaption: function(obj){
return obj.caption;
}
},
instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( 
[
{ url: 'http://www.site.com/img/nameimg1.jpg', caption: 'description'},
{ url: 'http://www.site.com/img/nameimg2.jpg', caption: 'description'},                     
{ url: 'http://www.site.com/img/nameimg3.jpg', caption: 'description'},                     

], 
options 
);
instance.show(0);

}(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

}
```

html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="startSwipe();"><img src="/img/ico1.png" border="0" /><br>Gallery</a>
```

I hope someone in the future will serve to.